# Getting error with Apple Swift tutorial (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

Tags: swift

I have been going through [this Apple tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Dl1.png), which I believe is written in Swift 2 code so I am having to edit things a bit for Swift 3.

Now I am stuck at a point where I am receiving the error `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. What is this and what should I be looking for, and how can I clear it up? See below screenshot...

[image]

Comment: You need to set an exception breakpoint and show us the stack where the error actually occurs.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17802723/74815).

Comment: @i_am_jorf ok added different image. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: @rmaddy that is for a very old version of XCode and it did not help me at all as I do not see the errors he is referring to. I see nothing in my code errors that tells me what the problem is.

Comment: Set break points to find which part of your code is causing a crash.

Comment: That tutorial is just as valid for Xcode 8 as it was when written. None of it has changed.

Comment: @rmaddy actually several things are different, one for example being the slider at the bottom of navigator to show all stacks. It's not on 8.

Comment: So Xcode now shows the full stack trace instead of you needing to move a slider. That doesn't make the rest of what it teaches about debugging any less useful.